# Importing a new python file when a button is pressed in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to load up a quiz that is in a separate python file when a button is pressed in one of the menus. I tried to use import, however it causes the other python file to run straight away, rather than only when the button is pressed, how would I fix this?

```
import FSMQuiz1

def selectTask():
            screen7 = Toplevel(screen5)
            screen7.geometry("600x450+686+254")
            screen7.title("Select a task")
            Label(screen7, text = "Please select a task...", font = ("Calbiri",14)).place(relx=0.25, rely=0.044, height=41, width=304)
            Button(screen7, text = "Finite State Machines", command = FSMQuiz1).place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2, height=54, width=117)
```

Answer (score 0):

what if you use the python build in function exec?

you can use this function to load a file:

```
def exec_file(file_name):
    #open the file
    with open('your/file.txt') as fh:
        #read it
        data = fh.read()
    #execute it
    exec(data)
```

Comment: The quiz is in another python file, with its own tkinter screen commands.

Comment: so make an function that calls this function with the right path

Answer (score 0):

You can use importlib to load python files.

```
from os import path
from importlib.util import module_from_spec, spec_from_file_location

spec = spec_from_file_location("module.name", path.join(PATH, 'file.py'))
module = module_from_spec(spec)
spec.loader.exec_module(module)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
import FSMQuiz1

def selectTask():
            screen7 = Toplevel(screen5)
            screen7.geometry("600x450+686+254")
            screen7.title("Select a task")
            Label(screen7, text = "Please select a task...", font = ("Calbiri",14)).place(relx=0.25, rely=0.044, height=41, width=304)
            Button(screen7, text = "Finite State Machines", command = lambda: FSMQuiz1).place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2, height=54, width=117)
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the button command in a define, then use the command to call it, eample:

```
def CallButton():
    import FSMQuiz1
def selectTask():
            screen7 = Toplevel(screen5)
            screen7.geometry("600x450+686+254")
            screen7.title("Select a task")
            Label(screen7, text = "Please select a task...", font = ("Calbiri",14)).place(relx=0.25, rely=0.044, height=41, width=304)
            Button(screen7, text = "Finite State Machines", command = CallButton).place(relx=0.15, rely=0.2, height=54, width=117)
```